Shared memory for Inter-process communication performs worse than pipes and system v queue throughput-wise
I am developing an application on an ARM64 platform and benchmarking inter-process communication methods. My tests compare the performance of shared memory, pipes, and System V message queues. Surprisingly, I have discovered that shared memory, which I anticipated would offer the fastest throughput due to reduced copying and lower overhead, actually performs worse than both pipes and System V message queues. I am seeking insights into why this might be happening and how I can optimize it.
To measure throughput, I use clock_gettime with CLOCK_MONOTONIC to record a start timestamp before the sender process begins transmitting data, and a stop timestamp once the receiver process has received the entire data.
The tests are conducted on ARM64 architecture, specifically on a PicoCore™MX8MP module.
The tests in detail can be viewed here: https://github.com/KjellbergD/IPC_test/tree/main/files/ipc-experiments
For shared memory, no synchronization or locks are required as write only happens from the sender.
I've conducted detailed timing analyses to pinpoint performance bottlenecks. Specifically, I recorded timestamps on the sender process immediately before creating the shared memory space and immediately after to capture the precise duration of its creation and data copying. Similarly, I measured the time it takes for the receiver to attach to the same shared memory space by taking timestamps that encapsulate this process only. The summed durations from these separate measurements are consistent with those obtained from an end-to-end timing measurement (from data sending start to reception completion). Despite this detailed breakdown, the overall performance results remain unchanged.
Here are the results when running on my own device compared to the PicoCore:
Own Device (x86-64):
type size(MB) latency(ms) throughput(MB/sec)
pipes 1 1.700 588.2000
pipes 4 5.080 787.4000
pipes 16 20.654 774.6000
pipes 64 78.338 816.9000
pipes 256 291.878 877.0000
pipes 512 599.711 853.7000
shared 1 1.128 886.5000
shared 4 4.201 952.1000
shared 16 14.075 1136.7000
shared 64 58.787 1088.6000
shared 256 221.928 1153.5000
shared 512 395.928 1293.1000
queue 1 1.651 605.6000
queue 4 4.911 814.4000
queue 16 19.063 839.3000
queue 64 71.049 900.7000
queue 256 294.923 868.0000
queue 512 536.234 954.8000

PicoCore:
type size(MB) latency(ms) throughput(MB/sec)
pipes 1 2.463 406.0000
pipes 4 6.882 581.2000
pipes 16 22.260 718.7000
pipes 64 85.234 750.8000
pipes 256 333.581 767.4000
pipes 512 665.159 769.7000
shared 1 2.795 357.7000
shared 4 9.454 423.1000
shared 16 36.306 440.6000
shared 64 141.735 451.5000
shared 256 572.561 447.1000
shared 512 1134.393 451.3000
queue 1 2.288 437.0000
queue 4 7.145 559.8000
queue 16 26.403 605.9000
queue 64 106.813 599.1000
queue 256 425.763 601.2000
queue 512 853.392 599.9000


I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem.

Please post some minimal code showing what exactly you are measuring (the link to the entire github project is not forbidden. But a question should be understandable as is, without the need to follow an external link. Besides, if you can't summarize the question with a few line code, that means that it is probably too much work to ask for volunteer here to analyze the code).

How much memory on the board?  Are you running into paging problems because the shared memory is too large compared with the physical memo?

My first thought tho (again, I haven't read anything from your github project) is that the difference between shm and pipe is not very high on x86 neither. And on x86, I know for sure that shm worth it. So I am wondering what exactly you are timing. Usually, when people talk of SHM vs pipe, it is for situations where a process hold some data, want to delegate some work with another process, and therefore to share data with that process. If it has to use a pipe, then it needs to copy the data through a pipe. But if that main process has stored its data, from the start, into a shared memory

then it is almost free. But of course if what you do is copying anyway, then what you compare is the difference between copying in memory and copying via pipe. Pipe are very efficient, usually. Not faster than simple memory write, but not hugely slower neither.

Is the the shared memory test counting the time to create the actual physical shared memory pages and map them into both processes address space?  That's something that would only have to be done once so should be counted separately.
